# "The Package System is Broken" on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I got a window pop up onto my screen, and it said "Updated software is available for this computer. Do you want to install it now?" So I clicked "Install Now",which led to this window;

> #### The package system is broken
>
> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
>   Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
>   Transaction failed: The package system is broken
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   linux-generic: Depends: linux-image-generic (= 5.3.0.45.38) but 5.3.0.45.38 is installed
>                  Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 5.3.0.45.38) but 5.3.0.42.36 is installed

***I know that this is a duplicate question, but I've looked and found no questions like this that are up-to-date or with answers***
I have Ubuntu 19.10 on my early 2011 MacBook Pro.
Thank you for reading this. Please reply if you know of anything I can do!

Comment: What happened that broke your package system? You must fix that first.